# Unable to access to Gerrit API

Tags: python, curl, gerrit

Hi I am trying to use Gerrit API's https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html

I have used curl tool to call APIs.

curl -X GET --user http_username:http_password --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" https://gerrit_url/changes/12345

Getting response as **not found**. Please help if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

There's an "a" missing in the URL:

```
https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/12345
```

Answer (score 0):

That because you used wrong input of **ChangeId**. You took ChangeNumber.

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#get-change

As the doc mentioned *GET /changes/{change-id}* such as

```
GET /changes/myProject~master~I8473b95934b5732ac55d26311a706c9c2bde9940
```

Change-id *The ID of the change in the format "'~~'", where 'project', 'branch' and 'Change-Id' are URL encoded. For 'branch' the refs/heads/ prefix is omitted.*

So solution is one of below:
1-use correct change-id
2-use *Query Changes* instead of *Get* Change, such as
`GET /changes/q/{change number}`